# R: Cannot load .rda file into R Studio --> cannot open compressed file 'ESL.mixture.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Tags: r, file, upload, load

I am new to R and trying to figure out how to load a data file into RStudio.  The file is ESL.mixture.rda and comes from this site: [link to data in Non-Linear SVM Classifier section](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/support-vector-machines-r)

I saved the file into a folder on my local machine.  I right click the file and select --> Open --> I get the following dialog box:

[image]

The following code appears in my console: load("C:/Users/redacted/Desktop/redacted/ISYE6501/ESL.mixture.rda")

But the output I get is strange.  The dataframe shows weird characters instead of actual values.

[image]

If I did my steps correctly, I should be able to run the following code:

```
load(file = "ESL.mixture.rda")
names(ESL.mixture)
```

Right now I cannot and get the following error.

```
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'ESL.mixture.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: to your second problem concerning the ```load(file = "ESL.mixture.rda")```command: I think the file is not in your working directory and so the error occurs.
Concerning the RStudio problem: What version do you use? What OS? I tried it and all works fine on my machine.

Comment: Perhaps the file is corrupted. I downloaded it and opened it without the same results (it looks like a normal `list` to me), which suggests the problem is solely on your machine. `system("md5sum path/to/ESL.mixture.rda")` for me yields `84675fc832972b5d2e9387b8c478b273`, please confirm you have the same checksum before we go down other rabbit-holes. (And a size of exactly 167772.)

Comment: @J_F:  sorry for the dumb question but is there a way for me to find what my working directory for R is?